# CakePHP virtualField and displayField for several objects

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I have a little problem with the `displayField` in combination with `virtualFields`.

I have a **File** that **belongsTo** 2 different **Users**.

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Creator' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'creator_id',
    ),
    'Editor' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'editor_id',
    )
);
```

As `virtualField` and `displayField` in the User Model. I use the following code:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
  'full_name' => "CONCAT(first_name, ' ',last_name)"
);

public $displayField = 'full_name';
```

Creating a new File works fine, but if I want to view all my files I get the following error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'first_name' in field list is ambiguous

I already read about it a little here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html
At the end there are some limitations about virtualFields, so I tried to add this to the Controller:

```
$this->virtualFields += $this->Creator->virtualFields;
$this->virtualFields += $this->Editor->virtualFields;
```

But somehow this doesn't change anything.

Hope you can help me with this little problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to add the Model name to the field name, e.g, `'full_name' => 'CONCAT(User.first_name, " ", User.last_name)'`?

Comment: Yes, but I get an error that says "User.first_name" not found because he is looking in "Creator.first_name"

Comment: Yes, you would need to use the correct Model name from where you want to get `first_name` and `last_name`.

Comment: Read the section on [Virtual fields and model aliases](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-and-model-aliases). Their code should work perfectly for you.

Comment: Not found => You forgot to join in the relation..

Comment: Thanks AgRizzo, I don't know how I could miss that?
That solved my problem!
How can I mark your post as useful?
Or do you want to create an "Answer" so I can set the problem to "solved"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need 2 virtual fields:

```
$this->File->virtualFields = array(
    'Creator__full_name' => "CONCAT(Creator.first_name, ' ',Creator.last_name)",
    'Editor__full_name' => "CONCAT(Editor.first_name, ' ',Editor.last_name)"
);
```

Comment: Tried this as well. Unfortunately it's not working.

This code worked for me:
Thanks to AgRizzo for the link:

`public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
        $this->virtualFields['name'] = sprintf(
            'CONCAT(%s.first_name, " ", %s.last_name)', $this->alias, $this->alias
    );
}`